# How to reduce file size of rgl postscript?

Tags: r, rgl

I plotted a 3d surface using `rgl` which I want to save as a pdf. Even though the plot is fairly simple, the file size is close to 1Mb.

```
require(rgl)

f <- function(x,y) {
    d <- 3 * sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    exp(-0.02 * d^2) * sin(d)
}

x <- y <- seq(-pi, pi, length=50)
Grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
z <- matrix(f(Grid$x, Grid$y), length(x), length(y))

rgl.open()
rgl.viewpoint(phi=-60, theta=0, fov=30, zoom=.8)
surface3d(x, y, z, color="black", front="lines", lit=FALSE)
rgl.bg(color="white")

Sys.sleep(1) #to give rgl some time to render
rgl.postscript("surface.pdf", fmt="pdf") 
Sys.sleep(1)
print(file.info("surface.pdf")$size)
# 880K
```

Setting `lit=FALSE` already reduces the file size considerably.

How else can I reduce the size of this Figure?

Thanks!

(Since I want to add more elements to the plot, `lattice::wireframe` is not an option.)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, I tried printscreen (yes, the keystroke), after enlarging the `rgl` device window, removed the borders and saved as PNG. The image file was around 45 kb and looked much better...

Comment: You are right, but I prefer to save my figures as vector graphics.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft , does printscreen provide better output that `rgl.snapshot()` ... ??

Comment: @BenBolker, LOL. Call it a 'brute force' snapshot. Didn't knew this function. I've tried it, and the file is even smaller than the PNG saved from printscreen.

Answer (score 1):

In general I also prefer vector graphics, but the situation here is that rgl renders the scene. This means that the pdf is composed of many of small pieces - which is why the file size grows fast. In fact, your pdf consists of lots of tiny straight lines. `lit = FALSE` means that these lines are not split into even tinier lines with different colors.

These pieces are also visible in the pdfs at higher magnifications, so I often go for bitmap graphics in this situation (particularly if a surface is rendered). To get a decent resolution, I `rgl.snapshot` a large window. No tperfect, but a working compromise for me (I use snapshots of "3d" graphs rather as eye-catchers or for overview info and not as quantitative visualization).

---

Inspecting the pdf, I found that there are 2 copies of each line, possibly one for front and one for back, or one from each neighbouring polygon. Playing around a bit with the `front` and `back` parameters  of `surface3d` points in direction "neighbour polygons".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand now that it does not make much sense to ask OpenGL for a vector graphics output of an already rendered scene. I also agree that the pdf does not look very much like a vector graphic at large magnification. However, I do not understand that last remark about "neihbour polygons".

Comment: @sieste: I rendered with `back="cull"` (which I think should suppress producing background polygons), and still found lines on top of each other.